# Como enviar 2 listas por JsonResult

Tags: c#, ajax, json, mvc

lo que quiero hacer es enviar 2 listas en un metodo JsonResult y recibirlos en el Ajax. Debido a que tengo una tabla de muchos a muchos, necesito cambiar los ID por nombres. Por lo que necesito que me retorne el nombre de las cosas.

```
public JsonResult GetHerramientas(int ID)
    {
        List<tbl_ListaHerramienta> servicioH = db.tbl_ListaHerramienta.Where(x => x.Id_datos == ID).ToList();
        List<tbl_Herramientas> herramienta = db.tbl_Herramientas.ToList();
        var result = new { Result = servicioH, herramienta };
        return Json(result);
    }
```

¿Cómo puedo enviarlo y como lo recibo en el Ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes generar un diccionarios de objeto y enviarlo en el resultado.

```
public ActionResult GetHerramientas(int ID)
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                result.Add("servicioH ", db.tbl_ListaHerramienta.Where(x => x.Id_datos == ID).ToList());
                result.Add("herramienta ", db.tbl_Herramientas.ToList());                
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Recuerda cambiar el tipo del control a ActionResult